# start apache with 404 with mac

Tags: apache, configuration

I'm trying to install start apache2 on my own computer but get some problems:

so when I do:
sudo /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start
it gives me:
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using xxxs-MacBook-Pro.local for ServerName
httpd (pid 685) already running

and when Im trying to open "http://localhost/" it gives me 404. Is that because the default directory is wrong?

(I also tried to fix the the servername and in my httpd.conf it has #ServerName www.example.com:@@Port@@
and I changed it to ServerName localhost but doesn't work.)

Comment: Did you install apache from scratch when osx has it already? Normally you manage it through launchctl via: service, or using httpd

Comment: Well that confuses me because to start apache on a mac you just need to make sure web sharing is enabled in your system prefs -> sharing. Apache will be running already. Restarting it is: `sudo httpd -k restart`. Are you specifically having trouble after having edited apache configs and now it doesn't work properly?

Comment: ahhh I figured out. yes I did changed part of apache configs. you're right! now I fixed it thanks!